# Upgraded to Magento 2.3.2 and get this error main.CRITICAL: Payment Error: The authenticity of the gateway response could not be verified. [] []

Tags: authorize

I ran a test via Authorize.Net and the charge went through but on the client side it says  "The authenticity of the gateway response could not be verified" and does not accept the order. Any idea why?

Comment: are you using sandbox account? did you use production account? Also, checkout this link and try out things specified there? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56490220/2869218

Comment: No I'm not using Sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it turns out that somehow that the sequences went out of wack. I imported some orders from another Magento site but when I looked in the table sequence_order_1 the numbers started changing for some weird reason. I set them back to a proper order and it fixed my issue.